# How do i get rid of new line from a return string?

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP script that just returns the string "hi"
Here's the code:

```
<?php include "base.php"?>

<?php
echo "hi";
?>
```

In xCode I get the following:

2014-12-15 10:56:24.048 MyApp[12515:1603] resultString =

hi

For some reason it adds a new line before the string. How can I prevent this new line from being generated?
Is it the way I'm encoding the string? Here's my string

```
NSString *resultsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

THIS WAY IT WORKS!!

```
<?php
include "base.php"

echo "hi";
?>
```

Comment: To start debugging `NSLog(@"returnData: %@", returnData);` to see exactly what is received from the server. Or use Charles Proxy to see the exact data returned by the server. You will see that the server is returning a leading newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't offer much help with the Objective C side of things, but does there happen to be a stray newline in your php file? Remember, anything outside of the `<?php ?>` tags is interpreted literally in PHP. Try removing the closing `?>` - this is actually preferred for pure-code PHP files, since the end of the code implies closing the code block and it prevents trailing newlines from affecting anything.

Comment: I just updated my php code (see above). I forgot to include the first line of code (importing a file). I didn't think it was relevant because I'm just including a file. However. I removed the closing ?> in that statement, removed the <?php before my echo. This way I only have one <?php and one closing ?>  For some reason this solved the issue.

Comment: In php, when you have any text outside of `<?php ?>` tags, that exact text goes straight to the output. This includes new lines. You had a newline between your two code blocks, so that newline went into your output.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope someone else can benefit from this info. I have included a block of code that shows how it can be done to avoid any new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

```
//Assuming below string after reading from PHP
 NSString *resultsString = @"\nhi";

//So try below api to replace new line
    NSString *modifiedString = [resultsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",modifiedString);
```